# Grid Puzzle Solvability

Tags: permutations, puzzle, rubiks-cube

I've created a unity game which is sort of like a flat two sided Rubik's Cube. There's a grid (with a dynamic number of rows and columns) and set of tiles numbered from 1 to rows*columns. These tiles are randomly placed on the grid, and the goal is to put them back in order with 1 in the top left. When you click on two adjacent tiles, the row or column of tiles shifts, and the tile that gets pushed off the grid reappears on the opposite edge. If you push it off the right it reappears on the left, if you push it off the top, it reappears on the bottom, and vice versa. However, some randomized initial positions lead to unsolvable states. Is there some sort of equation for the solvability of a puzzle like this, similar to the solvability equation for the [15-puzzle](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~mdr/teaching/modules04/java2/TilesSolvability.html)?

Comment: This is a very interesting puzzle game! By any chance could you send me the unity file so I could test it :D?

Comment: I think this is a nice question, but (unless somebody else created the game before you, and it became as popular as the 15-puzzle), I doubt anyone knows a solvability condition -- and I bet one's actually fairly hard to come up with (maybe not though). From a practical standpoint, instead of randomly initializing by just numbering squares, you could apply a sequences of random moves to shuffle a solved board.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that, as it'll take much longer to implement. I suppose that's my best option though. Thanks.